# marker icon don't load in next js app react-reaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'am working in map app with next js typescript and react-reaflet, when i add a marker it's show me nothing i don't know why there is my code and my result :

you will find here the part of my map code, with all importation and all what you need to help me please

```
"use client";

import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet"; // Assurez-vous d'importer L depuis Leaflet

const carIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: "./iconMarker.png",
    iconRetinaUrl: "./iconMarker.png",
    iconSize: [100, 100],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
})


interface MapProps {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ lat, lng }) => {
  // Personnalisez l'icône du marqueur
  const customIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: require("./iconMarker.png"), // Chemin vers votre icône personnalisée
    iconSize: [20, 20], // Taille de l'icône
  });

  return (
    <MapContainer
      style={{ width: "40rem", height: "20rem" }}
      center={[48.8566, 2.3522]}
      zoom={13}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[lat, lng]} icon={carIcon}>
        <Popup>
          Une jolie popup CSS3. <br /> Facilement personnalisable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX8i2.png)